# Why is the equation $z=(x+y)^2+y^2$ a paraboloid?

Tags: analytic-geometry

Why is the equation $z=(x+y)^2+y^2$ a paraboloid?, as the right side is expanded, it is $z=x^2+2xy+2y^2$.

The equation of a paraboloid in some sources is simply  $z=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}$ and there is no the product of $x$ and $y$ in the equation.

Answer (score 2):

A paraboloid is something which can be described by such an equation after possibly making a change of coordinate. On the right hand side, if you replace $x = x' - y$ you get the standard form, $z= (x')^2 + y^2$.

Comment: what do you mean by making change of coordinate?

Comment: Well in the answer we changed from (x,y,z) coordinates to (x',y,z) coordinates. The shape is the same but viewed from a different angle. In general a change of coordinate usually mean making an invertible linear substitution like above.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $z={x^2\over a^2}+{y^2\over b^2}$ isn’t **the** equation of a paraboloid, any more than ${x^2\over a^2}+{y^2\over b^2}=1$ is **the** equation of an ellipse in the $x$-$y$ plane. Those sources you quote likely mentioned somewhere that this is the equation of a paraboloid in “standard position,” that it’s the “standard form” of the equation, or some other wording along those lines. It describes an elliptic paraboloid that has its vertex at the origin, the coordinate axes as its principal axes, and opens “upward” in the direction of the positive $z$-axis. Often, we also assume that $a\ge b$. This is a very special subset of all possible elliptic paraboloids.

The paraboloid that you have has been rotated approximately 32° from this standard position, which you can see if you plot the surface. If you were to apply the inverse rotation to it, you’d end up with an equation in the standard form. We don’t need to do this, however, as the original form of the equation of this paraboloid makes it easy to find its *spectrum*, which can be used to distinguish among the various types of quadric surfaces: it’s $(1,1,0,-1)$, which is the spectrum that all elliptic paraboloids have. (Compare this to, say, the spectrum of an ellipsoid, which from the standard equation is $(1,1,1,-1)$.)

Answer (score 0):

You may get rid of the term in $xy$ by performing the transformation $$x=u+\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}v,\,y=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{ 
2}u-v,$$ which gives you an equation in standard form.

Comment: The $uv$ term still there. You need $x=u+\phi v,\ y=\phi u-v$ with $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2$ to keep an orthogonal basis and eliminate $uv$.

Comment: @zwim Oh, thanks. That's true. The squares here have different coefficients.